# Matching specific file names

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, augeas

I have some code that looks for net script files eg: ifcfg-eth0 etc. The code currently uses the match function available in Augeas to get all the files in the directory e.g.:

```
augeas.match("/files/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*")
```

However this code is matching files such as ifcfg-eth0.bak which is not a valid file for my needs. I want to match only the network scripts ranging from eth0 to eth7 (and no backup files etc). What would be a good approach to match only the correct files?

Comment: That depends on what is a valid file for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If your absolutely sure you don't want any files that have and extension you could try this.

augeas.match('etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*[regexp("[\w-]")]')

Editied to add quotes as mentioned below.

Comment: Since the match function takes only 1 string argument this is not working. Do you think this could be modified in some way to achieve the argument requirements?

Comment: No, what's not working is that it's missing quotes in the brackets. The rest seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to meet my requirements using the following code:

```
files = []
for i in range(8):
    try:
        filename = augeas.match('/files/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth' + str(i))[0]
        files.append(filename)
    except:
         continue

print files
```